# Implement AWS Cognito authorization to control RDS mysql records

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-rds

In my react application, once a valid user logs-in to my app, he will be redirected to the dashboard where he can see all the products. If there are 10 products available in AWS-RDS-Mysql-Table called `Products-Table`, he will see all 10 products.

For this, I'll make a backend API endpoint `/products` call and it get gets me all products by running a simple sql query : **`SELECT * FROM Products-Table`**.

So far so good.

---

My Current AWS pipeline basic flow: **`ReactApp => (api request comes to) HTTP API gateway => LAMBDA (nodejs) => RDS (mysql)`**

I also have **Cognito user pool + Lambda authorizer**. I have setup a basic authentication flow using **lambda authorizer** to check if request is valid or not. All this is working fine.

My Cognito groups & Users.

eg.

```
AdminGroup:
               User1
               User2

WorkersGroup:
               User3
               User4
```

Currently it doesn't matter If I login with AdminGroup's users or  WorkersGroup's users. Every time I see 10 products.

**Is the below scenario possible using cognito and AWS IAM roles/policies concept** ?

When I login with AdminGroup's users, I should be able to see all the products.
BUT
When I login with WorkersGroup's users, I should be able to see **ONLY 5 product (Let's say)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognito is providing application level security and does not filter queries, as it doesn't know how. Specifically, Cognito can't answer the question on how to filter `Products-Table` to the user and/or user group.
This has to be implemented in software, meaning in the `LAMBDA (nodejs)` part of your application.

AWS has documentation an this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-enable-cognito-user-pool.html among other solutions.
In short:

1. Configure Cognito User Groups
2. Configure API Gateway to use Cognito Lambda Authorizer
3. Configure API Gateway to provide the information to Lambda ("claims")
4. Program the `LAMBDA (nodejs)` to retrieve this information and adjust the query as needed for the user/group

I think you have done 1 + 2 already, but are missing 3+4.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will explore claims and get back. Meanwhile would you mind helping me for : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75038243/aws-http-api-gateway-lambda-node-express-internal-server-error & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75221992/lambda-runtime-failed-to-post-handler-success-response-http-response-code-413